# How do I use BeanUtils.populate to populate a bean from a form which has a checkbox

Tags: java, forms, jsp, boolean, javabeans

I am guessing I may be missing something simple here but I have done a lot of searching and have not found the answer...

#### Summary

How can I use the ready made libraries which support JavaBeans to help me take a checkbox from an HTML form and use it to populate a boolean field in a JavaBean which will then be used to update a database table?  If this isn't going to work what approach would be best?  Ultimately I am trying to avoid writing field specific code in what is, in all other respects, generic code.

#### Description

1. I have a jsp file (addScreen.jsp) which displays a form.
2. I want to use the data which is entered into the form to populate a JavaBean (type Screens).
3. I will then use the JavaBean (via Hibernate) to update a record in a database table.
4. The database table (Screens) contains a column, enabledFlag which has a boolean type.
5. The way I have represented this in the html form is as a checkbox.
6. In my controller code, when I process the form I want to use the elegant and generic functionality provided to support JavaBeans.
7. So I am trying to use the BeanUtils.populate() method to take data from the HTML form and use it to populate the `screen` field of type `Screens`.
8. This approach works very well for most of the fields in `screen` and converts the data from the form into the right type and stores it within the screen JavaBean.
9. But **(and here is the problem)** it **doesn't** process the checkbox and create a true or false value to go into the Boolean field within the `Screens` JavaBean.  In fact it always leaves that field populated with `false`.  I'm guessing it doesn't do anything and it defaults to false.
10. I think I can see why this doesn't work exactly as I have done it (but feel free to correct me).  The way the checkbox state is recorded in the HttpServletRequest parameters probably isn't going to reflect what BeanUtils.populate() is expecting so it can't do anything useful.  But I am not sure what it is expecting so I don't know how to manipulate the input so that populate() gives the right answer (not sure if that is very clear).

#### So given the above, my questions are:

1. Is there anything fundamentally wrong with what I am trying to do - i.e. use BeanUtils or other general purpose JavaBean library to populate a JavaBean from an HTML form which includes a checkbox?  If so please let me know a better way of achieving my goal.
2. Assuming that there isn't a fundamental problem with what I am trying to do, am I using the wrong method or approach or should I be manipulating the data in some way before calling populate() so that it interprets the checkbox correctly?
3. Any other tips about how to go about this?

I have tried to include some relevant code below without swamping readers with irrelevant detail, but feel free to ask to see more if it would help.  All feedback welcome.

### Code Snippets

#### Form from addScreen.jsp which includes the enabledFlag checkbox

```
<form id="editScreen" method="post" action='Controller.do'>
    <table>
        <col class='label' />
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Screen Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='name'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Enabled?:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="enabledFlag" value="Enabled" checked>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <input type='submit' name='addButton' value='Add'>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

#### Declaration of enabled flag within Screens JavaBean

```
private boolean enabledFlag;

@Column(name = "EnabledFlag", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 0, precision = 0)
@Basic
public boolean isEnabledFlag() {
    return enabledFlag;
}

public void setEnabledFlag(boolean enabledFlag) {
    this.enabledFlag = enabledFlag;
}
```

#### Call to BeanUtils.populate()

```
BeanUtils.populate(data, request.getParameterMap());
```

`data` is of type `Screens` and `request` is the `HttpServletRequest` containing the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - the value of your flag is "Enabled", try something like "true", "on" or "1".

Or do you have mapping code that maps "Enabled" to true?

Also, there seems to be a problem when the checkbox is unchecked, as in that case, nothing is sent to the server - there seems to be a common solution in using Javascript to set a hidden field to a value "on" or "off" and considering the hidden field only, and ignoring the checkbox itself.

See here for further reference: http://books.google.de/books?id=KNjkjBDEKssC&lpg=PT107&ots=9wZRkd_Y48&pg=PT107#v=onepage&q&f=false